# Vim - web Preview files in Browser

Tags: vim, gvim, web-development, vim-plugins

I have been toying around with vim. I have too many plugins and unknown things in my vim rc.
Going to start again with it basic.

Wanting to get back into vim and use it as a web editor. One thing I can't figure out is how to preview the file in a browser and have the browser change on source change.

Is this possible, if yes how please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me applaud you for your decision.

Second, the topic as been discussed to death with no real conclusive answer:

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166049/is-there-a-live-html-preview-plugin-script-for-vim)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708154/open-current-file-in-web-browser-in-vim)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371674/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-examine-html-output-with-vim)
- [elsewhere](http://www.google.com/search?q=vim+live+reload+html+browser)

Comment: so there is livereload for chrome and firefox http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86242-how-do-i-install-and-use-the-browser-extensions-      The exec function in the second solution doesn't appear to work. If I can figure it will have a look.

Comment: I've never managed to make livereload work reliably. I settled for a browser extension that reloads the page every x seconds. It sounds dumb but it works better than the smart solutions.